# On my netbook, how can I disable the touch pad while I'm typing to avoid bumping it?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, netbook, touchpad, eee-pc

I'm getting very frustrated with this. I know I can use an external mouse and disable the touch pad, but that isn't always convenient.

I'm running Windows 7 on an EEEPc 900HA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Windows XP and the Synaptics driver is installed on your Eee PC you can find advanced settings here:

[image]

edit: install the Windows Vista Driver from the **[Synaptics support page](http://www.synaptics.com/support/drivers)** (no Win7 driver available yet, but the Vista driver works.

*(I'm 99% sure, the 900HA features the Synaptics touchpad, the ElanTec touchpad for the Eee PC was introduced later with the 901)*

If you want to disable the touchpad altogether, try **[TouchFreeze](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Windows-Widgets/System-Utilities/TouchFreeze.shtml)** or MS **[DevCon](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272)** (can't say whether they work with 7 though).

Comment: I'm also 99% sure that that the 900HA has the Synaptics touchpad. I never thought to install the driver because 1) no Win7 version and 2) it works out of the box. Never thought to try the Vista drivers, should work. I'll respond when I get home tonight to try it. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work. There aren't any options to disable while typing. Am I missing something? There are only options to change button actions in that properties dialog. Any help?

Comment: no, you can't disable the touchpad, only adjust the sensitivity, edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Is the link to TouchFreeze correct? It's linking to the Synaptics site.

Comment: it is now :) sorry

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but I was finally able to download TouchFreeze and it works great. Thanks!

Comment: very well, good to know it works with Windows 7

Comment: You can also cut out a piece of construction paper and place it over the touchpad.  I did this on a computer that would not allow it to be disabled.  The added benefit was that you could re-enable it easily just by removing the paper from the touchpad.  So the touchpad stops crashing into the mountain resulting in such a travesty and allows it to abide nicely while you are typing.

Answer (score 5):

[**TouchFreeze**](http://code.google.com/p/touchfreeze/) is exactly what you're looking for, **the touchpad is disabled only when you are typing**:

> Annoyed when you are typing a document
>   and accidentally the palm of your hand
>   brushes the touchpad, changing the
>   position of the cursor in your
>   document or accidentally clicking on
>   an option. TouchFreeze is simple
>   utility for Windows NT/2000/XP that
>   solves this problem. **It automatically
>   disables touchpad while you are typing
>   text.** Like syndaemon on x-windows.

Comment: As of now, it supports Win7, too.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on you OS (with the eee-pc I assume it's some linux variant) you may be able [to configure the touchpad](http://sprayfly.com/2009/08/23/disable-the-touchpad-whilst-typing-on-the-asus-eeepc-1005ha-in-ubuntu/) - those instructions are for Ubuntu, but maybe be useful for other distributions (not sure what is native on the eee-pc).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your model, there may be a switch on the keyboard to switch off the track pad. You can switch it off before doing a bunch of typing, it's little more effort than clicking a mouse button.

Answer (score 0):

There are often options in touchpad drivers to disable the trackpad while typing.  Since you don't say what hardware or OS you have, there's no way to be more specific.

Comment: Updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Control Panel / Mouse / Pointer Options.
Is `Hide pointer while typing` unchecked ?

[image]

Comment: No, it's checked.

Comment: If you uncheck it and click OK, there's a good chance that the problem is solved.