# How to disable the touchpad in Windows 7 while typing?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, touchpad

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is the easiest way to disable the touch pad on a laptop?](https://superuser.com/questions/13803/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-disable-the-touch-pad-on-a-laptop)
>   [On my netbook, how can I disable the touch pad while I’m typing to avoid bumping it?](https://superuser.com/questions/48272/on-my-netbook-how-can-I-disable-the-touch-pad-while-I'm-typing-to-avoid-bumping)

is there a program or setting that allows to disable the touchpad while I'm typing, and then enabling again when I stop typing?

My laptop is an HP Pavilion 2220, but it will rock if it's a generic solution.

Comment: A few duplicates. http://superuser.com/questions/48272/on-my-netbook-how-can-i-disable-the-touch-pad-while-im-typing-to-avoid-bumping . http://superuser.com/questions/13803/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-disable-the-touch-pad-on-a-laptop . Touchfreeze http://code.google.com/p/touchfreeze/ seems best for you.